# How to make a continuous connection between php and python

Tags: php, python

I want to make a real time application. So here is the scenario-
I have data coming to my computer through one of my COM port, which then is fetched by python and shown. For this I have used just a simple python `serial` module which reads the data via serial port and shows it.

Now this data is local to me. For high-end purpose, I need this data to be posted to one of my online website, which has **apache** webserver running, which will show the data worldwide.

So for real-time, I need to continuously monitor the serial port, take the data it, and post it continuously to the web-server (PHP end). (Reading the serial data and posting it to server run in parallel).

Now the problem is-

1. How do I monitor the data coming from COM port *in parallel* to posting it to webserver?
2. If I am sending data continuously, How do web-server get to know if the data is continuous? For this approach, I thought to save the data to database of webserver and make PHP script to continuously monitor the database. Tell me a better approach if you have

Comment: what's the data? how is it used?

Comment: its the google map data coming from gps threw COM port. I need to be updated continuously to website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, when dealing with a real time application which receives on one interface and sends on another, you will need a few threads and at least a couple of queues.
If you want your program to be event driven (highly recommended!) you should also include events which trigger when input is received.

For your problem I would suggest:

1 Thread for COM reading
1 Thread for COM writing (if you need to write)
1 Thread for PHP writing
1 Thread for PHP reading (if you need to read)
1 Queue for COM input
1 Event for COM input

You would have the COM reading thread write into the COM input queue each time some data is received on the com port, you can validate this data before putting it in the queue if you wish.

Then the COM input queue will set the COM input event to true, which is acting as a 'stop' for the PHP writing queue.

The PHP queue will then loop through all things that have been added to the COM input queue until it is empty, set the COM input event to false, and wait for more input before looping through again.

Make sure the Queue is thread safe, or put a mutex around it, here are a couple of links to things that may help you:

[Python Lock](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Lock)
 [Python Event](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#event-objects)
 [Python Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects)

---

For the web server side of things, you should use an http [`POST`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) message when sending data to the web server, depending on what you put in the request, you can send the data to a script on the web server which will validate, process and store it.

Unfortunately i'm not an expert at this aspect though so I can't give many hints.

Comment: So here again, a basic question rises. I suppose,have the PHP queue, full with data and now I am posting it to my webserver. I need to do that continuously. So how the webserver do know that the data is coming?I mean the Google Map I am using on web-server will change according to each page refresh then, But how do I make it synchronous?

Comment: make what synchronous? using this architecture you will instantly send any data you receive (depending on transmission delays) to the PHP webserver. You should use the `"POST"` method to send the data, which should trigger some event in your php code which will process it.

Answer (score 0):

On the Python side the easiest way is by having two threads. Thread 1 will read from the serial line, with blocking calls, and put all the data it reads into a [thread-safe queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html). Thread 2 will grab whatever is on the queue, post it to the remote PHP, (retry until successful), sleep for 2 seconds and repeat.

The PHP script called from Python will just have to insert the data into a database. The front-end PHP script will grab the data from the database and show it.

Comment: So how does the Python check if the data post to PHP been successfull?

Comment: That is the purpose of HTTP status codes. The PHP script will have to  make sure to return a status code of 200 if the data was received and stored successfully, 400 or 500 otherwise. See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html